# How to specify and read properties in an Eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, properties, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have an Eclipse product which uses my own plugins. I want to read some properties based on user inputs. I want to persist these properties on some user action, and read those properties back when required. Can this be achieved using some Eclipse API?

A more elaborate description of the above problem:

Say I have a property `abc=xyz` in a config file `myconfig.ini`. This property is read by the perspective during the bootstrapping process. During use of the perspective, some action sets this property to a new value `xyz=def`. Now, I should be able to save the new value in `myconfig.ini`. So next time the bootstrapping happens, the value of `xyz` is read as `def` instead of `abc`. However, I can also choose to manually set it to `abc` by editing the `myconfig.ini` file.

1. How would I manage `myconfig.ini`? Where should it exist within my eclipse product project?
2. What is the best API to manage reading, writing and updating properties in `myconfig.ini`?

Comment: The eclipse preferences API could help you http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipsePreferences/article.html

Comment: @RenéLink This seems to be preference configuration - I was looking more like persisting property values in an ini file for example. Do you know if I can use the IMemento interface to achieve this? Can you provide a code snippet?

Comment: The IMemento is intended to save an arbitrary object's state. Normally when an editor is saved and restored (close and reopen eclipse)- It does not support scopes like the preferences api. I would prefer the preferences api as it supports scopes and also supports default values.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [resource markers](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/resAdv_markers.htm) mechanism:

```
IMarker marker = file.createMarker(IMarker.MARKER);
marker.setAttribute(IMarker.MESSAGE, "blabla");
marker.setAttribute("attr", 5);
```

You can search for markers by using the `findMarkers` methods on `IResource`. 
See [FAQ](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_create_my_own_tasks,_problems,_bookmarks,_and_so_on?) also

Comment: Would I be able to persist these properties to some config file?

Comment: Does this go in the direction for configurations? Looks like they are intended for something else... or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using the apache configurations API http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/

It can read and write INI files and if you want to change the configuration file type or add more configuration options you can simply configure it.

I would add a hidden directory to the workspace root e.g. `${WORKSPACE}/.productName/product.ini`
and add an [ISaveParticipant](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/resAdv_saving.htm) that ensures the ini file gets updated on shutdown.

You can get the Workspace using the ResourcesPlugin

```
  IWorkspace workspace = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace();
```

and resolve it to an absolute path

```
  IWorkspaceRoot wsRoot = workspace.getRoot();
  IPath wsPath = wsRoot.getRawLocation();
  IPath absoluteWsPath = wsPath.makeAbsolute();
```